# Create data partition in R for chickweight dataset

Tags: r, modeling, data-transformation, linear-model, model

I am working on the ChickWeight Dataset in R.How should I split the data set to test and train using createdatapartition function and which field should I consider for partitioning of data?

There are weight,time , chick and diet data available in the dataset.
I am not sure which one should I be using to partition the data.

Comment: Partition on `chick` (the ID for each of the fifty birds).  In effect  you would have the data from a given number of birds, build and train your model, and then test it on a new, or at least different, set of birds. Consider taking a similar fraction from each of the diets (Diet 1 has twenty birds while 2, 3 and 4 have ten birds each)

Comment: Thanks! I have coded it this way referring to an example Train <- createDataPartition(ChickWeight$Chick, p=0.5, list=FALSE) I am not sure about what the P value and List values mean literally,I am assuming it as percentage for train dataset that is 50 % and list is FALSE i am not sure about this,and also I would like to know how to validate this which parameter should I look into.

Comment: See my answer for some possible code

Answer (score 1):

Partition on `Chick` (the ID for each of the fifty birds).  In effect  you would have the data from a given number of birds, build and train your model, and then test it on a new, or at least different, set of birds.

Consider taking a similar fraction from each value of `Diet` (Diet 1 has twenty birds while 2, 3 and 4 have ten birds each)

The following code seems to put $70\%$ of the chicks with each diet into the training set and the remainder into the test set

```
data(ChickWeight)
set.seed(1)
ChickDiet <- unique(ChickWeight[,c("Chick","Diet")])
selected <- createDataPartition(ChickDiet$Diet, list=FALSE, p=0.7)
TrainChicks <- ChickDiet[selected, "Chick"]  
TrainChickWeight <- ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick %in% TrainChicks,] 
TestChickWeight <- ChickWeight[! ChickWeight$Chick %in% TrainChicks,]
```